# Map a URL to local Blog

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, hosts

I would like to type `/blog` in my url and have it go to my locally hosted WordPress page at `http://localhost/wordpress`

I modified my host file to redirect blog to the localhost. Now apache display the 'It works!' page. But I need it to redirect to http://localhost/wordpress

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

While simply changing the documentroot for your website to the wordpress directory would do the trick, it wouldnt redirect to /wordpress like you want.

I'd suggest using a rewrite rule for this in the apache config.

RedirectMatch ^/$ wordpress/